# Using custom permissions in view after log in django

Tags: django, permissions

I have 3 types of users in my models.py

```
class Customer(models.model)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name=‘Customer’)

class ClientTypeA(models.model)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name=‘ClientA’)

class ClientTypeB(models.model)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name=‘ClientB’)
```

I was using permissions in my base template to render the correlating sidebar, but now I am also incorporating a specific dashboard for each user along with the sidebar, so I find it would be simpler to create home views for each of the user types.

Once I log a user in it redirects them to my home view - so I came up with this in my views.py

```
def home(request):

    if request.user.is_customer:
        return redirect(customer_home)

    elif request.user.is_clientA:
        return redirect(clientA_home)

    elif request.user.is_clientB:
        return redirect(clientB_home)

    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html')
```

The redirects called will simply take them to there corresponding home pages.

1. I know my is_customer, is_clientA, is_clientB do not automatically come with django, how and where do I add these custom permissions? to my models.py? What would I set them equal to in order to simply check is the type of user active? Do I even need custom permissions or is there a simpler way to call the type of user?
2. Am I using to many if statements? (I'm trying to keep it simple and fast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the models have one-to-one fields to the `User` model, you can use `has_attr` to check whether the user has a row for that model. You don't have to create permissions.

```
if hasattr(request.user, 'customer'):
    return redirect('customer_home')
```

If you only have three customer types, then the if/elif/else is probably ok. As the number increases, you can change it to something like the following.

```
customer_types = [
    ('customer', 'customer_home'),
    ('clienttypea', 'ClientA_home'),
    ...
]

for field_name, redirect_url in customer_types:
    if hasattr(request.user, field_name):
        return redirect(redirect_url)
# fallback
return render(request, 'home.html')
```